# Spotbugs - write Detector, that finds unwanted imports in a java class

Tags: java, spotbugs

How can I find unwanted imports in a java class with a SpotBugs Detector?

Right now I'm trying to extends BytecodeScanningDetector and overrite visit(...) methods.
But I can't seem to find the information (originating package of variables) that I want.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, checkstyle can do this https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/imports/IllegalImportCheck.html

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar the only problem is, that Checkstyle does not find code within a method like "org.assertj.core.util.Lists.newArrayList()" because there is no import if you fully qualify the 'unwanted class'.

But apart from that, it helps for a lot of occurrences, thank you!

Comment: You may want to report the FQN issue to [Checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle).